# How to remove element from array inside for-of loop?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a loop on this form in a code base I'm working on.

```
for(const foo of data) {
    foo.bar = getValue();
}
```

I want to change this, so that I remove the element `foo` if a condition based on `foo.bar` is satisfied. Is this possible within the for-of loop? Or do I need to use another approach? This is my attempt, but I don't feel secure about it. It really looks like one of those things that works until it does not.

```
for(const x of data) {
    foo.bar = getValue();
    if(foo.bar > 5)
        data.splice(data.indexOf(foo), 1);
}
```

I know that I could filter the array after creating it. Would that make more sense?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to create a new array and assign it? Mutation, especially in this case could result in some unforseen side effects, no? I don't tried it, but just mentioning

Comment: The index gets wrong if you start removing items in an array while looping, but you could start looping from the end with a normal `for(let i = data.length-1...)`.

Comment: @LingVu I'm not very skilled in js, but yes, I was afraid that mutation would be an issue. And I want to change the code as little as possible.

Comment: Why not a filter? `data2 = data.filter( x => getValue(x) > 5)` or something

Comment: @JeremyThille It just felt more natural to do it inside the loop. But I'm a C coder. :)

Comment: That's another XY problem (many problems posted here are). You want to filter an array (problem X), but you don't know how to do that, so you try to make a `for` loop in which you want to remove elements (problem Y), but you don't know how to do that either, so you ask help about what you believe will solve your original problem (Y), instead of the original problem itself (X).

Comment: @JeremyThille I understand what you mean. In this case the for loop was already there, and I wanted to avoid changing it if I could.

Answer (score 1):

It makes more sense to [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array previously to avoid mutating the array you are looping ([splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) mutates the array).

That way is clearer, easier to debug and you also get to avoid side effects.

Comment: Ok, I'll use that then